# Sort Range Ignoring "" Flavor of Blank on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Spreadsheet Layout]

I have a spreadsheet with 2 main columns. 

Column A is the student's name. 

Column B is the student's grade.

Other columns (not shown) list various information about the student that the end users input.

End users click on the Data Validation Arrow to select the student in Column A, and the student's grade is auto populated in Column B.
The formula in Column B is:

```
=IF(A2="","",Index(All!$B:$B,Match(A2,All!$A:$A,0)))
```

The **All** sheet contains a master directory of the Students and their Grade level assignment.

**The Problem:**

When users attempt to re-sort the data using the Sort A-Z menu option in B1, it includes the blank cells in the sort - The blank cells come first, moving all the relevant data to the bottom of the sheet. 
I understand that G-Sheets considers "" to be text. Is there another method to write my formula that would keep the Grade column blank, but allow for the sorting feature to function as end users would expect?

[image: Sort Function]

Comment: I don't think the issue is blank rows in just the Grade column, but that you have blank rows right across your "data filter" range.  So any sort you do for that whole range covered by the data filter, from A1 to XX:9999 (or whatever) will always have blank rows somewhere.  If you expect to be able to sort any column, and in either direction - ie. sometimes sort Grade highest to lowest, and sometimes lowest to highest - I don't see a way around this, unless you add other columns where you present a filtered view of that data.

Comment: It might be clearer if you shared a copy of your sheet, without sensitive data.  But I think this is fundamentally a challenge when you are trying to use this area of the sheet both for data entry, ie adding student's names and then auto-filling adjacent columns, and also using it for sorting and other review/analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can implement two additional comments where you filter the results before sorting them:

`=SORT(FILTER(A2:B,not(B2:B="")),2, true)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning "" in the IF statement, I instead returned an absolute reference to a blank cell that I knew would remain blank (I also added a comment and a protected range to that cell to ensure it would). This is working for me for sorting using the right-click menu at the top of the column.